# RegEx Decimal Range

Tags: regex

I don't even know where to start with decimal ranges.  I'm looking for a one line pattern for range .0015 to .008.  Thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but this is much easier to achieve using code than it is regex...

Comment: Using regex, however, what about `^\.00(?:1[5-9]\d*|[2-7]\d*|80*)$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much easier to achieve using code than it is regex, but to answer your question with a regex, you can use the following.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/vRR481/1)

```
^\.00(?:1[5-9]\d*|[2-7]\d*|80*)$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\.00` Match this literally as `.00`
- `(?:1[5-9]\d*|[2-7]\d*|80*)` Match either of the following options

  - `1[5-9]\d*` Matches 15-19 with any number of any digit following (i.e. 151, 199999, etc.)
  - `[2-7]\d*` Matches 2-7 with any number of any digit following (i.e. 200, 799999, etc.)
  - `80*` Matches 8 followed by any number of `0`s (i.e. 8, 80000)
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Thanks!  It's for a number range in Blackboard our LMS.  They use RegEx only unfortunately.